# Is my cat lonely?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, multi-pet-families

We adopted an adult cat from an animal shelter (about 1 year old), he was very skinny and slept a lot, and soon we discovered he is FIV positive.

So far he underwent treatment, gained some weight, and is much more active. He doesn't play often, doesn't seek human company and prefers to keep to himself. Although he is okay with my wife's company when relaxed, he is easily spooked by me. He rarely seeks attention from any of us. Now he got to meow sadly through the house, and likes to hangout in the balcony. We think he is very solitary and misses cat company, and we want to get a female FIV positive to be his friend. He is neutered.

Do you agree with this assessment? Is a good idea to get another cat?

Comment: Not a full answer, but male cats usually live solitary and protect their territories against invading males. Introducing a new cat can take several weeks and mean stress for both of them.

Comment: I don't think your cat is ever going to feel alone, cats by nature could live their entire lives on their own and never feel any loneliness, cats could enjoy social contact with other cats but it's not essential and they don't feel lonely if they don't have it at all, also nobody could guarantee that the new cat and your cat are going to socialize well, only little kittens are easy to socialize but your cat being 1 year old is an adult.

Answer (score 1):

Cats are like people, some seek out attention while others are perfectly happy to be alone.

It is hard to tell what your cat had been through up until you guys gave him a forever home. Being I'll at first didn't help & now that he is feeling better he is just taking his time getting used to his new normal.

Have patience...just give him space & let him know you care by giving him a special treat when he seeks your attention or maybe one a week etc.

Once he decides that you are forever he will probably settle in but it will be on his terms.

I wish you the best!